# Meanjs using passport authentication dynamic redirectURL

Tags: passport.js, meanjs

The meanjs template creates an OAuth call back function that looks like

```
/**
 * OAuth callback
 */
exports.oauthCallback = function(strategy) {
    return function(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate(strategy, function(err, user, redirectURL) {
            if (err || !user) {
                return res.redirect('/#!/signin');
            }
            req.login(user, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return res.redirect('/#!/signin');
                }

                return res.redirect(redirectURL || '/');
            });
        })(req, res, next);
    };
};
```

I would like to dynamically set the redirectURL but I don't know where to set it.
I would like to call something like

```
<a href="/auth/facebook/?redirectURI=url to direct to after success" class="undecorated-link">
            <img src="/modules/users/img/buttons/facebook.png">
        </a>
```

Is there a better way of doing this or is there something already built in for this?